# TCLK error when I run 'validate' from the rms package

Tags: r, rms

I'm running Rstudio 0.98.501 with R 3.02 on OSX Mavericks 10.9.1. I have XQuarts installed. I have loaded these packages:

library(foreign)
library(Hmisc)
library("ggplot2")
library(gdata)
library(MASS)
library(rms)

Then I do this I do this:
model1 <- lrm(Y~xvars, data=devset, x=T, y=T)

val.model1 <-validate(model1, B=50)

I get this error:

Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj") 
[tcl] invalid command name "toplevel".

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: FYI, this can happen with other packages that use Tcl, such as `pROC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hej!

I had the same issue and when running the following command in R - as suggested there: http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/Rcmdr/installation-notes.html - I realised that there was a remnant tcl/tk 8.5 installation on my system.

system("ls -ld /usr/local /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libtcl*")

`drwxr-xr-x  12 root  wheel      408 24 Oct 02:21 /usr/local
drwxrwxr-x  61 root  wheel     2074 30 Oct 22:43 /usr/local/lib
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  4820229 21 Oct  2008 /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.5.dylib
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  1419604 30 Mar  2013 /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    11072 21 Oct  2008 /usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.5.a
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     4824 30 Mar  2013 /usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.6.a`

Removing the old 8.5 files fixed the problem for me.

HTH

Comment: Later versions of `rms` do not use `tcltk` unless requested.